# How to check if panda dataframe group have same data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe as below

```
id  name  Base   field1    field2           field3
1   AA     Y      Yes      Consumer         Not Applicable 
1   BB     N      Yes      Consumer         Not Applicable 
2   CC     Y      Yes      Consumer         Not Applicable 
2   DD     N      Yes      Not Applicable   Not Applicable 
2   EE     N      No       Not Applicable   Modified
3   FF     Y      Yes      Not Applicable   Applicable 
3   GG     N      Yes      Not Applicable   Not Applicable 
3   HH     N      Yes      Not Applicable   Not Applicable
```

The expected result is to group this dataframe based on the ID column and check if the data on all the other columns are the same data in each group, and finally write the results.

I tried this to validate the data on each group but it always says TRUE

Code:

```
result_list=[]
for col in df.columns:
        result = df.groupby(level=0)[col].apply(lambda x: len(set(x))==1)
        result_list.append(result)

final = pd.concat(result_list,1)
```

The expected result is

```
id  name     field1   field2           field3           Error
1   AA       Yes      Consumer         Not Applicable   Pass 
1   BB       Yes      Consumer         Not Applicable   Pass
2   CC       Yes      Consumer         Not Applicable   field1, field2, field3 mismatch for ID: 2
2   DD       Yes      Not Applicable   Not Applicable   field1, field2, field3 mismatch for ID: 2
2   EE       No       Not Applicable   Modified         field1, field2, field3 mismatch for ID: 2
3   FF       Yes      Not Applicable   Applicable       field3 mismatch for ID: 3
3   GG       Yes      Not Applicable   Not Applicable   field3 mismatch for ID: 3
3   HH       Yes      Not Applicable   Not Applicable   field3 mismatch for ID: 3
```

Any help on this?

Comment: What's your desired result, only `id = 1` passes your test?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the dataframe and expected result. let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get what you want with the code (assuming that `df` has index named `id`):

```
def handler(df):
    for col in ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']:
        if df.loc[:, col].nunique() > 1:
            return 'error in {} for id {}'.format(col, df.index[0])
    else:
        return 'pass'

result = df.groupby(level=0).apply(handler)
result = df.reset_index().merge(result.to_frame().reset_index(), on='id')
```

`result` is:

```
   id name field1          field2          field3                         0
0   1   AA    Yes        Consumer  Not Applicable                      pass
1   1   BB    Yes        Consumer  Not Applicable                      pass
2   2   CC    Yes        Consumer  Not Applicable  error in field1 for id 2
3   2   DD    Yes  Not Applicable  Not Applicable  error in field1 for id 2
4   2   EE     No  Not Applicable        Modified  error in field1 for id 2
5   3   FF    Yes  Not Applicable      Applicable  error in field3 for id 3
6   3   GG    Yes  Not Applicable  Not Applicable  error in field3 for id 3
7   3   HH    Yes  Not Applicable  Not Applicable  error in field3 for id 3
```

**EDIT** - minor editions in handler

```
def handler(df):
    cols = list()
    for col in ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']:
        if df.loc[:, col].nunique() > 1:
            cols.append(col)
    if cols:
        return 'error in {} for id {}'.format(', '.join(cols), df.index[0])
    else:
        return 'pass'
```

Comment: Hi Poolka, however, this code satisfies almost the expected results. But, on the error column, it's not showing if the data mismatches on more than field. For id 2: it should write as Field1, Field2 & Field 3 mismatch for ID:2. Any thoughts?

Comment: The data comparison always happens on the first field of the list and other fields are skipped.

Comment: @Osceria The code in the answer is the basis that works and performs something pretty close to what you want. Feel free to modify it (column names, handler, and so on) to meet your expectations. About the issue in the comment - check the EDIT addition.

Comment: It works perfectly for my requirements after making slight changes. I just posted another post with a similar question but with an extra check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53295685/group-pandas-dataframe-validate-with-condition

Answer (score 1):

You could `groupby` id and then `agg` each column calculating the number of `unique` values per group and then you know there is a mistake where that number is greater than 1:

```
df[df.columns.drop('name')].groupby('id').agg(lambda x: len(x.unique()))>1
```

With this output, based on which you could construct your string.

```
    field1  field2  field3
id          
1   False   False   False
2   True    True    True
3   False   False   True
```

Comment: -This helps. What if the column names to be validated differ in different iterations. I run this piece in a for loop which iterates with different data frames(df1,df2) and the columns of df,df2 and df3 are different. So, I don't want to hardcode the names of the fields which keep changing for other dataframes

Comment: See the edit, you can pass the columns list dropping the 'name' column and then you can pass any other number of fields..

Comment: Okay. In case I add another column(Base) to the dataframe(edited). For every group based on ID, there will be only one 'Y' and other rows in the group will be 'N'. Here, the values of the rows where Base='Y' should be the reference and other rows with Base 'N' should be validated against it. The distinct columns on each row should be noted as an error column. Any thoughts?

Comment: That completely changes the scope of the question and the solution, I would suggest writing another question with a different input and output for clarification..

Comment: Okay. Posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53295685/group-pandas-dataframe-validate-with-condition