# Group Pandas Dataframe & validate with condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Dataframe:

```
id   Base   field1    field2    field3
1     Y      AA         BB        CC
1     N      AA         BB        CC
1     N      AA         BB        CC     
2     Y      DD         EE        FF
2     N      OO         EE        WT
2     N      DD         JQ        FF
3     Y      MM         NN        TT
3     Y      MM         NN        TT 
3     N      MM         NN        TT
```

The expected result is to group this dataframe based on the ID column, 2 validations should be performed.

1. first check if there is only one Base value 'Y' in each group. If its only true, then this row should be taken as a reference to validate step 2, else write the error as "More than one base Y found for ID" and proceed with step 1 for next ID
2. Validate if data on all the other columns that have "Base:N" match with the data on the columns where Base is 'Y', and write the names of fields that are not matching in the error column. product column is a unique field and it can be ignored for comparison of data.
3. Repeat this for all the ID int the dataframe.

The expected result is

```
id  product Base  field1  field2  field3   Error
1   A        Y     AA       BB      CC     Reference value
1   B        N     AA       BB      CC     Pass
1   C        N     AA       BB      CC     Pass
2   D        Y     DD       EE      FF     Reference value
2   E        N     OO       EE      WT     field1, field3 mismatch    
2   F        N     DE       JQ      FF     field1, field2 mismatch 
3   G        Y     MM       NN      TT     more than 1 Y found for id:
3   H        Y     MM       NN      TT     more than 1 Y found for id:
3   I        N     MM       NN      TT     more than 1 Y found for id:
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom function:

```
def f(x):
    #boolena mask for compare Y
    mask = x['Base'] == 'Y'
    #check multiple Y by sum of Trues
    if mask.sum() > 1:
        x['Error'] = 'more than 1 base Y found for id:{}'.format(x.name)
    else:
        #remove columns for not comparing with not equal
        cols = x.columns.difference(['Base','product'])
        mask1 = x[cols].ne(x.loc[mask, cols])
        #if difference get columns names by dot
        if mask1.values.any():
            vals = mask1.dot(mask1.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ') + ' mismatch with base' 
            x['Error'] = np.where(mask, 'Base: Y', vals)    
        else:
            x['Error'] = np.where(mask, 'Base: Y', 'Pass')    

    return x

df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(f)
print (df)
   product Base field1 field2 field3                              Error
id                                                                     
1        A    Y     AA     BB     CC                            Base: Y
1        B    N     AA     BB     CC                               Pass
1        C    N     AA     BB     CC                               Pass
2        D    Y     DD     EE     FF                            Base: Y
2        E    N     OO     EE     WT  field1, field3 mismatch with base
2        F    N     DD     JQ     FF          field2 mismatch with base
3        G    Y     MM     NN     TT  more than 1 base Y found for id:3
3        H    Y     MM     NN     TT  more than 1 base Y found for id:3
3        I    N     MM     NN     TT  more than 1 base Y found for id:3
```

Sample DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
                   'product': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'], 
                   'Base': ['Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N'], 
                   'field1': ['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'DD', 'OO', 'DD', 'MM', 'MM', 'MM'], 
                   'field2': ['BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'EE', 'EE', 'JQ', 'NN', 'NN', 'NN'], 
                   'field3': ['CC', 'CC', 'CC', 'FF', 'WT', 'FF', 'TT', 'TT', 'TT']})
df = df.set_index('id')
print (df)
   product Base field1 field2 field3
id                                  
1        A    Y     AA     BB     CC
1        B    N     AA     BB     CC
1        C    N     AA     BB     CC
2        D    Y     DD     EE     FF
2        E    N     OO     EE     WT
2        F    N     DD     JQ     FF
3        G    Y     MM     NN     TT
3        H    Y     MM     NN     TT
3        I    N     MM     NN     TT
```

Comment: @Osceria - Can you ediit your question ?

Comment: Tried the same code with the same dataframe, not getting the expected results. Actual results in the Error column is: "base: Y" in all the rows where base is 'Y' and "Error, field1, field2, field3 mismatch with base" in all rows where base is 'N'. The code doesn't capture the errors "more than 1 base Y found for an id:", only should highlight the fields where values are not matching.

Comment: @Osceria - Can you test sample dataFrame data if working for you? Answer was edited.

Comment: tried with my sample dataset, not returning the expected results. Edited the question with more details

Comment: @Osceria - Do you test my sample dataframe? not working for you? I see only change in text, so no idea why not working for you. Also for `DE       JQ      FF     field1, field2 mismatch` was in input data changed `DE` to `DD`, so not matched first value in my solution. If not working, can you explain more?

Comment: In this code, I'm replacing these 2 lines to add the columns directly from the dataframe that need to be compared, but it is throwing this error.                                                  
cols = x.columns.difference(['Base','product']) and 
mask1 = x[cols].ne(x.loc[mask, cols])"                                                  
updated code:              cols = dfdata.columns
mask1 = x[cols].ne(x.loc[mask, cols])
Error- "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis".   Any reason why this error? @jezrael